# A rocking rebus. Find the song!

Tags: rebus, music

***What is the meaning of this strange rebus?*** The solution is the name of a song, and the title may help to narrow the scope just a little further.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, "Hello" reminds me of something... by someone... can't put my finger on it...

Comment: @AMACB. You should try looking at it "from the other side", maybe it rings a dell. Sorry...maybe it rings a BELL.

Comment: The image shows a combustion engine; the red part has no particular significance: https://openclipart.org/detail/172290/combustion-engine

Comment: Of course the OP decides to use Comic Sans. -1 (Just kidding, of course)

Comment: Can you give any hints?

Comment: There's a Bob Dylan song with those lyrics, minus hello, but it doesn't fit the engine.

Answer (score 7):

Is it:

> [See You Again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_You_Again_(Wiz_Khalifa_song)) by Wiz Khalifa?

Explanation:

> The rebus shows an engine (most probably a V8.) Which is very deary related to the movie series Fast and Furious. This song was composed for the 7th part in the movie series.

Answer (score 4):

> *Welcome to the Machine* by Pink Floyd?

Because

> the picture is of a machine with a welcome message superimposed on it.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! I edited your answer to include a brief explanation, since answers without justification here often get downvoted - hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, of course I don't mind.  I should have done it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> *Hello* by Antigone Rising?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if this is it, because of the obscurity, but...

> [Hello Explosion](http://music.volcanoisaband.com/track/hello-explosion) by Volcano

Because

> A combustion engine works off of continuous explosions.